# jdbc url for mysql is not working with IP address

Tags: mysql, jdbc

I want to connect to MySQL(*it's running on my local machine*) using JDBC. I am able to connect to MySQL using Url:

```
"jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306"
```

When I tried

```
"jdbc:mysql://192.xxx.xxx.xxx:3306"
```

I got errors.

I am working on Ubuntu & my `etc/hosts` file has this entry:

```
127.0.0.1   localhost 192.xxx.xxx.xxx
```

Any pointer on this?

**Edit:**

`my.cnf` has this enrty:

```
bind-address        = 127.0.0.1
```

`netstat -na | grep 3306` gave me:

```
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:3306          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN     
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:3306          127.0.0.1:57243         ESTABLISHED
```

Comment: Hope this help. http://superuser.com/questions/565563/how-do-connect-to-mysql-via-ip-not-just-localhost

Comment: @Jan yes its active on my machine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned in comments: The BIND-ADDRESS setting in my.cnf forced mysql to listen an 127.0.0.1 only so no network connect from outside is possible.

Remove bind address and you'll be fine.

Answer (score 0):

I think there is no need to bind the address so please remove bind address and get done. Note:- you need to restart mysql server.